# Can we run JScript to call excel object without MSOffice?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code in by ETL Shell Script task. below is the code. It is working fine in my system. When I ran it in server it failed. I noticed that MS Office is not installed in server. I tried installing office driver (AccessDatabaseEngine - Free distribution) but no luck. Can make this script running by just installing ActiveXObjet for excel? or is it done some other way? I can't ask client to install MS Office on server. Please suggest me an alternate.

```
main();
function main(){


var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

ExcelApp.Visible = false;
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
var filenamer="D:\\Net Drive\\Drive\\lator.xls"

var ExcelBook=ExcelApp.Workbooks.open(filenamer, false, false);
...
...}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to write a program (C#/Java) or does it have to be a scirpt?

Comment: You are running JavaScript/ActiveX on the server? JavaScript runs on the client so office would have to be installed on the computer it is running on, not the server. Running ActiveX locks you into being an IE only shop which is bad.

Comment: This code runs using windows command prompt (cmd.exe). I can even write java code on server. Open office is available on server.